# changing the value of a model property emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to achive a toggle effect in Emberjs for some dynamically loaded data. Here is my adapter:

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function(){
        return ajax('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/address-book/companies?includes=details')
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data.map(function(c){
                    return {
                        name: c.name,
                        website: c.details.data.website_url,
                        dev_website: c.details.data.development_website_url,
                        showDetails: false
                    };
                });
            });
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML handlebars:

```
{{#each m in model}}
    <tr>
        <td >
            <p style="cursor:pointer; color:#009688" {{ action 'displayDetails' m}}>{{m.name}}</p>
            {{#if m.showDetails}}
                <div class="">
                    <p><strong>Wesbite URL: </strong><a href="{{m.website}}">{{m.website}}</a></p>
                    <p><strong>Development Wesbite URL: </strong><a href="{{m.dev_website}}">{{m.dev_website}}</a></p>
                </div>
            {{/if}} 
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

and here is the controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchText: null,

    actions: {
        displayDetails: function(item){
            item.toggleProperty('showDetails')
        }
    }
});
```

I've also tried this in my controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchText: null,

    actions: {
        displayDetails: function(item){
            item.showDetails = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Which gives me the error I must use Ember.set to change the value of a property show then I did this:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchText: null,

    actions: {
        displayDetails: function(item){
            item.set('showDetails', true);
        }
    }
});
```

but this gives me the error `item.set` is not a function

Now I'm trying to switch the models showDetails property from true to false every time the company name (p tag) is clicked. I know what I did works with properties of the controller itself but how can I achieve this in my model object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `Ember.set()` as the message said?

```
Ember.set(m, 'showDetails', true);
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_set

Comment: I had not. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

you need either:

1) an item controller (soon to be deprecated)
    - looks into the 'needs' api for controllers
2) a component that you can set the property on.

You cannot set a model property for an individual object with an Array Controller.

If you had an identity map, you could do something like:

```
actions: {
  actionName: function() {
    this.store.find('modelName', someID).toggleProperty('propertyName')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter you have return as follows:

```
return response.data.map(function(c){
    return {
        name: c.name,
        website: c.details.data.website_url,
        dev_website: c.details.data.development_website_url,
        showDetails: false
    };
});
```

This means that you return array of plain JavaScript objects that does not have implemented `#set` method directly on them. Ember provides `Ember.set` that can be used both on Ember objects and JavaScript objects. What is more important, it is compliant with Ember's binding mechanism and probably this is the reason you got a warning.

To make your return objects more flexible in Ember environments consider wrapping them in Ember Object class. This way you would have straightly implemented `#set`, `#get` and `#togglePropert` method. As an example:

```
return response.data.map(function(c){
    return Ember.Object.create({
        name: c.name,
        website: c.details.data.website_url,
        dev_website: c.details.data.development_website_url,
        showDetails: false
    });
});
```

[More info about Ember.set](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_set)

[More info about #togglePropert](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_toggleProperty)